# How should I temporarily redirect a website to a different domain?

Tags: redirect, web, dns

We are powering down our data center for 12-18 hours during an infrastructure audit. We need to post a 'temporarily unavailable' message on websites affected by this outage.

In the past, I have changed the A-Record for the websites domain names to point to site hosted by a third party. The DNS changes appear to be instantaneous, but I worry about the potential 48 hour propagation lag.

Is there a better way to temporarily redirect a site during an outage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there won't be any server at the existing ip, you don't have any other option.

To minimize the propagation issue, a few days ahead of the time you need to switch, you should decrease the TTL of the A record to something very short (like a few minutes), which should force clients and dns servers to query your dns more often.